# Moyal Product in Non Commutative Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, commutator, non-commutative-geometry, deformation-quantization

Can someone please explain me what is a [Moyal product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moyal_product)?

Also, how does putting $$X_a(\psi) ~=~ x_a\star\psi$$ realise $$[X_a,X_b]=i\theta_{ab}{\bf 1}?$$

Ref: [Quantum mechanics on non-commutative plane](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0102050)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I) The associative non-commutative Moyal/Groenewold/star product $f\star g$ is explained on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moyal_product). 
The corresponding $\star$-commutator is defined as

$$\tag{1} [f\stackrel{\star}{,} g]~:=~f\star g-g\star f.$$

In particular, the [Jacobi identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_identity) for the $\star$-commutator is a consequence of the associativity of the $\star$-product.

II) On one hand, there is the algebra of functions, say, the algebra $\mathbb{C}[[x]]$ of powerseries in indeterminates $x_a$. We equip it with a unit $1$ and the $\star$-product$^1$ so that

$$\tag{2} [x_a\stackrel{\star}{,}x_b]~=~i\theta_{ab}.$$

III) On the other hand, there is the Heisenberg algebra $({\cal A}, +, \circ)$ generated by

$$\tag{3} [X_a\stackrel{\circ}{,}X_b]~=~i\theta_{ab}{\bf 1}.$$

Here the elements of the Heisenberg algebra are (linear) operators acting on functions; the algebra product $\circ$ is composition; the algebra unit ${\bf 1}$ is the identity operator; and

$$\tag{4} [A \stackrel{\circ}{,}B]~:=~A \circ B - B \circ A$$

is the usual composition commutator of two operators $A$ and $B$.

IV) There is a unique [algebra isomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_homomorphism)

$$\tag{5}  (\mathbb{C}[[x_a]],+, \star) ~\stackrel{\Phi}{\longrightarrow}~({\cal A}, +, \circ) $$

generated by

$$\tag{6} \Phi(x_a)~:=~X_a.$$

It follows that the algebra isomorphism $\Phi$ maps the (2) into (3).

V) The Heisenberg algebra acts on the algebra $\mathbb{C}[[x]]$, i.e. an operator $A$ acts on a function $\psi$ and produce a new function $A(\psi)$. Concretely, for an element $A\in {\cal A}$ define

$$\tag{7}  A(\psi)~:=~\Phi^{-1}(A) \star \psi. $$

Equivalently,

$$\tag{8} \Phi(f) (g)~:=~f \star g. $$

It is not hard to see that the definition (7) is consistent with that $\Phi$ is 
an algebra isomorphism.

--

$^1$ There is also the standard commutative and associative pointwise multiplication $\cdot$ of functions, which plays almost no role here.