# How to derive $[x_i, F(\vec p)] = i \hbar \frac {\partial F(\vec p)}{\partial p_i}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation) indicates that the following relation is "easily shown": $[x_i, F(\vec p)] = i \hbar \frac {\partial F(\vec p)}{\partial p_i}$, however I'm having some trouble showing it.  I think I'm just messing up the multivariable Taylor expansion (of $F(\vec p)$).  Can one of you walk me through it or link me to site that will?  Thanks.

---

Edit:
Here's what I get (without using $x=i\hbar \frac \partial {\partial p}$ which I haven't proven yet):

$$F(\vec p) = F(\vec 0) + \sum^3_{j=1} \frac {\partial F(\vec 0)}{\partial p_j}p_j + \frac 12 \sum^3_{k=1} \sum^3_{j=1} \frac {\partial^2 F(\vec 0)}{\partial p_k \partial p_j} p_j p_k + \dots$$
so
$$(x_iF(\vec p) - F(\vec p)x_i)\psi$$ $$= x_i[F(\vec 0)\psi -i\hbar \sum^3_{j=1} \frac {\partial F(\vec 0)}{\partial p_j}(\nabla \psi)_j + \hbar^2\frac 12 \sum^3_{k=1} \sum^3_{j=1} \frac {\partial^2 F(\vec 0)}{\partial p_k \partial p_j} (\nabla \psi)_j (\nabla \psi)_k + \dots]$$ $$- [F(\vec 0)x_i\psi -i\hbar \sum^3_{j=1} \frac {\partial F(\vec 0)}{\partial p_j}(\nabla x_i\psi)_j + \hbar^2\frac 12 \sum^3_{k=1} \sum^3_{j=1} \frac {\partial^2 F(\vec 0)}{\partial p_k \partial p_j} (\nabla x_i\psi)_j (\nabla x_i\psi)_k + \dots]$$

where $$(\nabla x_i\psi)_j=\frac {\partial x_i}{\partial x_j}\psi + x_i\frac {\partial \psi}{\partial x_j} = \delta_{ij}\psi + x_i\frac {\partial \psi}{\partial x_j}$$
and $$(\nabla x_i\psi)_j(\nabla x_i\psi)_k=(\delta_{ij}\psi + x_i\frac {\partial \psi}{\partial x_j})(\delta_{ik}\psi + x_i\frac {\partial \psi}{\partial x_k}) = \delta_{jk}\psi^2 + x_j \psi \frac {\partial \psi}{\partial x_k} + x_k \frac {\partial \psi}{\partial x_j} \psi + x_i^2 \frac {\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x_j \partial x_k}$$

Thus:
$$(x_iF(\vec p) - F(\vec p)x_i)\psi$$
$$=  x_i[F(\vec 0)\psi -i\hbar \sum^3_{j=1} \frac {\partial F(\vec 0)}{\partial p_j}\frac {\partial \psi}{\partial x_j} + \hbar^2\frac 12 \sum^3_{k=1} \sum^3_{j=1} \frac {\partial^2 F(\vec 0)}{\partial p_k \partial p_j} \frac {\partial \psi}{\partial x_j} \frac {\partial \psi}{\partial x_k} + \dots]$$
$$- [F(\vec 0)x_i\psi -i\hbar \sum^3_{j=1} \frac {\partial F(\vec 0)}{\partial p_j}(\delta_{ij}\psi + x_i\frac {\partial \psi}{\partial x_j}) + \hbar^2\frac 12 \sum^3_{k=1} \sum^3_{j=1} \frac {\partial^2 F(\vec 0)}{\partial p_k \partial p_j} (\delta_{jk}\psi^2 + x_j \psi \frac {\partial \psi}{\partial x_k} + x_k \frac {\partial \psi}{\partial x_j} \psi + x_i^2 \frac {\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x_j \partial x_k}) + \dots]$$

From here it doesn't look like those higher order terms are all going to cancel out.

Comment: It's basically analogous to this http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87038/

Comment: @Bubble That one is much easier (for me) because $F(x)$ is just a function whereas $F(p)$ is an operator and thus has to be Taylor expanded (I think?).

Comment: Actually in this case, I'm not even sure that $p_i$ makes sense.  Because $p$ isn't actually a vector is it?  It's $-i\hbar \nabla$.

Comment: $\nabla f$ for a function $f$ is a vector. $\nabla$ itself isn't a vector, but you can get away with pretending that it is. When people write $p_i = -i\hbar \nabla_i$ they really mean $p_i f = -i\hbar(\nabla f)_i$, which makes perfect sense. As long as you remember that $\nabla$ eventually acts on something, and that produces a vector, you can get away with pretending that $\nabla$ is a vector.

Comment: Hi @Bob Dylan. Comments: 1. Note that the position operator $\hat{x}^i$ and momentum operator $\hat{p}_j$ (up to a minus sign) enter on equal footing in the [CCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation), cf. above comment by Bubble. 2. Also note that the sought-for formula is independent of operator representation. E.g. one may work in the Fourier transformed momentum representation, or one may work in a formalism manifestly independent of representation.

Comment: Also related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/98372/25301

Comment: @RobinEkman it is more useful to view position and momentum operators as matrices with entries on the diagonal, especially as we transition to the Dirac formalism.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd say that $F(p)$ is an operator - it's a function of the momentum which may be equivalently represented as $F(x)$. Half of being really good at QM is being able change basis as needed. In QM, position and momentum are Fourier transforms of each other which is an amazing symmetry.

Answer (score 5):

As @Qmechanic pointed out in a comment, we are free to use any operator representation. In momentum space, $\hat{\bf x} = + i \hbar \ \partial/\partial {\bf p} $ and $\hat{\bf p} = {\bf p}$, so
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\left[\hat{x}_i,F\left(\hat{\bf p}\right)\right] &=& \left[i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial p_i},F\left({\bf p}\right)\right] \\
&=&  \frac{i \hbar}{f}\left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial p_i},F\left({\bf p}\right)\right] f \\
&=&  \frac{i \hbar}{f}\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial p_i}\left[F\left({\bf p}\right)f\right] - F\left({\bf p}\right)\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_i}\right)  \\
&=&  i \hbar \frac{\partial F\left({\bf p}\right)}{\partial p_i} \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Choose the momentum representation,

$$x_i = i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial p_i}$$

distribute $i \hbar$ and act the commutator on vector $\psi$,

$$[x_i, F(\mathbf p)] \psi = i \hbar \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial p_i}(F(\mathbf{p}) \space \psi) -F(\mathbf p) \frac{\partial }{\partial p_i} \psi \right)$$

and apply the product rule:

$$= i \hbar \left(\frac{\partial F(\mathbf p )}{\partial p_i} \psi + F(\mathbf p) \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial p_i}  - F(\mathbf p) \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial p_i} \right)$$

$$= i \hbar\frac{\partial F(\mathbf p )}{\partial p_i} \psi.$$

We left $\psi$ unspecified, so:
$$ [ x_i, F(\mathbf p ) ] = i \hbar \frac{\partial F( \mathbf p )}{\partial p_i}$$

Answer (score 2):

The [commutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator) of two variables, in some cases, can be related to [Poisson Bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket) via
$$
\left[\hat A,\,\hat B\right]=i\hbar\left\{\hat A,\,\hat B\right\}
$$
Thus,
$$
\left[\hat A,\,\hat B\right]=i\hbar\sum_i\left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial q_i}\frac{\partial B}{\partial p_i}-\frac{\partial A}{\partial p_i}\frac{\partial B}{\partial q_i}\right)\tag{1}
$$
Formally $\hat A=A(\hat q,\,\hat p)$ and $\hat B= B(\hat q,\,\hat p)$. *You should be able to use (1) to solve your problem.* Note, though, that this is not a solution that works in all cases (cf., [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/101831/) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46988/) that Qmechanic pointed out) as it is an approximation that only holds under certain cases.

A general solution involves the [Moyal bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moyal_bracket),
$$
\left[\hat A,\,\hat B\right]\sim\{\{\hat A\,,\hat B\}\}\sim \hat A\star \hat B-\hat B\star\hat A
$$
where $\star$ denotes the [Moyal star-product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moyal_product) (see answers on either [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/62857/) or [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19770/25301) for more on the Moyal product). The above then can be written as
$$
\{\{\hat A,\,\hat B\}\}=\{\hat A,\,\hat B\}+\mathcal{O}(\hbar^2)
$$
where $\{\cdot,\,\cdot\}$ here is the above Poisson bracket and $\mathcal{O}(\hbar^2)$ are corrections (referred to as *deformations* if the Poisson bracket).

Thus, Equation (1) becomes
$$
\left[\hat A,\,\hat B\right]=i\hbar\sum_i\left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial q_i}\frac{\partial B}{\partial p_i}-\frac{\partial A}{\partial p_i}\frac{\partial B}{\partial q_i}\right)+\mathcal{O}(\hbar^2)\tag{2}
$$

Comment: Comment to the answer (v1): The method of replacing quantum commutators $[\hat{f},\hat{g}]$ with classical Poisson brackets $\{f,g\}_{PB}$ may miss higher quantum corrections, cf. e.g. [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19770/2451), [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46988/2451) and [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/101831/2451) Phys.SE posts. For OP's question the Poisson bracket happens to give the precise answer.