# Conmutator of $[x, f(p)]$ on quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, momentum, commutator

I'm struggling trying to prove $[\overrightarrow{x}, f(\overrightarrow{p})]= i\hbar\frac{\partial f(\overrightarrow{p})}{\partial \overrightarrow{p}}$.

I already proved that $[x_i,p_i^n]=i\hbar \frac{\partial p_i^n}{\partial p_i}$ and I need to express $f$ in a power series but I don't know how to do that and derive the result.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hint: Try to utilize the linearity of commutator as well the linearity of derivative operator.

Comment: You don't know how to express $f$ as a power series?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to derive $[x_i, F(\vec p)] = i \hbar \frac {\partial F(\vec p)}{\partial p_i}$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/139142/how-to-derive-x-i-f-vec-p-i-hbar-frac-partial-f-vec-p-partial-p)

Comment: d_b, well now (s)he can learn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will not provide the full derivation, but will help you start your journey.

You can use the power series:

\begin{equation}
f(p) = c^{(0)} + c^{(1)}p \;+\; ...c^{(n)}\frac{p^n}{n!}
\end{equation}

Start looking at the commutator:

\begin{equation}
\left[x, c^{(0)} + c^{(0)}p \;+\; ...\frac{c^{(n)}}{n!}p^n\right]
\end{equation}

maybe look at it like:

\begin{equation}
\sum_n \left[x, \frac{c^{(n)}}{n!}p^n\right]
\end{equation}

Comment: I already read that in other pages, but I get confused because my teacher claimed: $f(p)=\sum_n \left(\overrightarrow{p}\overrightarrow{\nabla}\right)^nf(\overrightarrow{p})/n!$ so when I expressed the nabla operator in terms of momentun but I didn't arrive to the result.

Comment: Right so applying $\nabla^{n}$ to the Maclaurian Series should give you the first expression in my comments.  

In other words, the power series of expression 1 *is* the Maclaurian Series for some generic function of the momentum operator.  

If your teacher does not care whether or not you use the power-series approach, the link in the comments is more straight-forward.