# Commutation relation of position and Hamiltonian operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator, approximations

In the book **Quantum Mechanics volume 2 by Cohen-Tannoudji**, in Electric dipole approximation, it was written that [$\left[\boldsymbol{Z}, H_0\right]=i \hbar \frac{\partial H_0}{\partial P_{\boldsymbol{z}}}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/De9g0.jpg) where $H_0=\frac{P^2}{2m}+V(R)$, $V(R)$ is the central potential. How to derive this commutation?

Comment: see the answers in https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/139142

Comment: @Diego thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to derive $[x_i, F(\vec p)] = i \hbar \frac {\partial F(\vec p)}{\partial p_i}$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/139142/)