Schroedinger equation with value of wave function in polar coordinates?
I'm trying to get a better sense of what causes an increase in the magnitude and phase of the wave function at a given point. Is there a way to rewrite the schroedinger equation such that it explicitly denotes the magnitude and angle of $\Psi(x,t)$? I.e. denote $$\Psi(x,t)=r(x,t)\cdot e^{i\theta(x,t)}.$$ Can we rewrite the schroedinger equation in terms of $r$ and $\theta$ instead of $\Psi$? (Consider only the one-dimensional case for simplicity).

You can rewrite the SE in polar coordinates by transforming the operators to polar coordinates. What you have written is partly a change of phase (not sure what $r$ is), which makes no physical change to the wavefunction since it doesn’t affect the probability density.

See the Madelung equations. Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/373085/2451 and links therein.

@MattHanson, $r$ is the magnitude of the wave function.

Schrödinger equation written as a  product of a real modulus $R$ and a unitary phase $U$
$$\Psi(t,x)= R(t,x) U(t,x)$$
with $ R>0, U^* U = 1$, such that for a scalar wave function $U=e^{i\theta}$
one has
$$ i \hbar \partial_t R(t,x) U(t,x)= - \frac{\hbar ^2}{2m} \Delta (R(t,x) U(t,x)) + V R(t,x) U(t,x) $$
by the product rule
$$i \hbar \left( U  \partial_t R + R\partial_t U\right)  = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \left(U \Delta R + R \Delta U + 2 \nabla R \cdot \nabla U  \right)  + V R U $$
By multiplication with the unitary factor $U^{-1} = U^*$ from the left
$$i \hbar \left( \partial_t R + R  (U^* \partial_t U) \right)  = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \left( \Delta R \ + \  R \ (U^* \Delta U) \ + \  2 \  \nabla R \cdot (U^* \nabla U)  \right)  + V R U $$
which can be written with the real phase $\theta(t,r)$
$$U^*\ \nabla  U = e^{-i \theta} \ \nabla e^{i \theta} = i \nabla \theta$$
$$U^*\ \nabla \nabla U = e^{-i \theta} \ \nabla^2 e^{i \theta} = e^{-i \theta} \ \nabla  \left( i \nabla \theta e^{i \theta} \right) = i \Delta \theta  - (\nabla \theta)^2 $$
$$i \hbar \left( \partial_t R + i  R    \partial_t \theta \right)  = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \left( \Delta R \ + \  R \ (i \Delta \theta - (\nabla \theta)^2 ) \ + \  2 \ i \  \nabla R \cdot ( \nabla \theta)  \right)  + V R U $$
This nonlinearity in the phase $\theta$ renders the form useless  practically.

What is U? Could you define it in the answer?
