# Non-commutative field theory vs Non-commutative geometry

Tags: terminology, definition, non-commutative-geometry, non-commutative-theory

In the literature I have read about [non-commutative field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncommutative_quantum_field_theory) where the spacetime coordinates obey $$[x_i, x_j] = \theta_{ij}, \quad \theta_{ij} \neq 0.$$ However, I have also [non-commutative geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncommutative_geometry) described by a spectral triple $(\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{H}, D)$ where $\mathcal{A}$ is a unital algebra with a reperesentation on the hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and a self-adjoint operator $D$ which has some properties which I will skip. I wish to know how these two are related as I have not seen any literature which discusses both of them together even though both have noncommutative in their name.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/490010/2451